# RegExp: Поиск по "тэгам"

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, в нем конструкции вида

```
[if a==1]
Для пользователей1
[/if]
[else]
Для гостей
[/else]
[if a==2]
Для пользователей2
[/if]
```

шаблон: `\[([a-z]+)([^\]]+)*(?:\](.*)\[\/\1\])`

задача: найти все вхождения if/else.

Если встречается только один раз - все нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если два - получается вложенная конструкция
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как поправить шаблон?

Comment: Прочитать про жадность квантификаторов. Попробуйте использовать ревнивые, т.е. вида `*?`/`+?`

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/nJ9jU4/1

Comment: @Visman ответы в комментариях - наше все. Пусть модератор потратит время и вынесет его как полноценный ответ - у него ж много свободного времени. И другим пользователям жутко приятно - вы оставляете им возможность потратить время на оформление ответа, который внезапно повторит ваш!

Comment: @PashaPash, насколько знаю, сейчас у модераторов нет такой возможности, поэтому от ответа в коменте времени у него меньше не станет

Comment: @PashaPash, мой комментарий не ответ, так как там использован модификатор g, а он если не ошибаюсь только в js работает. Шаблон от автора вопроса у меня по какой-то причине не запускался вообще.

Comment: @BOPOH Да, сейчас это делается вручную. с ручной копипастой ответа и отметкой его как общего. А с вашей стороны надо было просто вписать ответ в текстбокс чуть ниже. "отвеченные в комментах" вопросы всплывают на главной раз в час, портят статистику и вообще мешают выходу из беты.

Comment: @Visman не обязательно. в С# модификатор g - это просто вызов метода Matches вместо Match. у TC явно g включен - иначе бы у него не нашлось нескольких совпадений.

Comment: @Visman, спасибо. g действительно был включен.

Comment: @AlexeyAndreev Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте нежадную выборку для текста между тегами:

```
\[([a-z]+)([^\]]+)*(?:\](.*?)\[\/\1\])
```

https://regex101.com/r/yV3iE2/1

Comment: спасибо, все получилось.

Comment: @Alexey Andreev,  тогда отметьте его как решение.